# Kubernetes list-like label values for network policy

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, kubernetes-networkpolicy

I am currently struggling with helm/kubernetes/network policies.

I have an application which needs to access a mongodb and a rabbitmq, both of which have their own network policy attached. Until now I only ever had applications which were affected by only a single network policy hence I thought it was a good idea to use label and label selector like `role: mongodb-client`.
What I am now realising is, that I cannot have two of those role labels in my yaml, which lead me to the idea of pluralizing it like `roles: mongodb-client,rabbitmq-client`.

I am also aware that I can use key-value pairs like `mongodb-client: 'true'` and `rabbitmq-client: 'true'` but I thought there might be a cleaner solution than to have this useless stringified boolean value attached.

As always, I greatly appreciate any input and hints!

Comment: Multiple labels with the same key never works (the API field is map[string]string) Did you see https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/40413 ?

Comment: Thanks for mentioning the issue, didnt come across it il now. Unfortunately there also is no answer, but an exam question was mentioned that states the problem I have